# Ruby syntax. What do "=~", "/ /i", "{2}" do in the following example?

Tags: ruby, syntax, combinations

```
raise NoSuchStrategyError unless some_string1[1] + some_string2[1] =~ /[RSP]{2}/i
```

I do not get the "=~ /[RSP]{2}/i" part.

If you guys have time to answer, I'd appreciate the help.

I mean what does =~ do in there?

What does "/ /i" do in there?

I have a guess that /[RSP]{2}/i produces all possible pairs out of [RSP]. Is that true? Why do we need / /i then? Why doesn't it produce pairs in irb, when I type /[RSP]{2}/i all I get from irb is

```
=> /[RSP]{2}/i
```

and not pairs.

Comment: As a side note: it seems that `SomeString1` is a variable, right? Then it's incorrectly named. Variables in ruby should **not** start with a capital letter. They should be named in snake case: `some_string1`.

Comment: edited SomeString to some_string, thank you Sergio!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a shortcut for regex (regular expression) match. It does not produce any pairs.

`=~` operator means "does left-hand value match right-hand regex?"

`/[RSP]{2}/` is a regex literal. You can write it instead of `Regex.new("[RSP]{2}")`

And, finally, trailing `/i` in regex literal means that this regex should be case-insensitive.

Comment: @ SrgioTulentsev If again you have some more time: what does [RSP]{2} do? Does this regular expression say that "The amount of equal symbols is supposed to be 2"?

Comment: @ViktorKaufman: that's regex syntax of saying "I want exactly two letters and each of them should be one of 'R', 'S', 'P'".